# passing multiple php variables into javascript function

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass multiple values from PHP into my javascript function.  The function is simple right now, just trying to show a popup with the values:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showMapsInfo(name, ctr) {
            alert('Info = '+name +' '+ctr);
        }//function showMapsInfo
    </script>
```

When I just pass in one value, name or ctr, it works fine.  However when passing in two or more values no alert occurs.  Is there a reason this isn't working?  I'm guessing if this is impossible I'll have to use AJAX to get the job done?

Here is the relevant PHP code.  I am making multiple forms on the page, every id is unique via a ctr.  I read in the $maps_name from a database.  This I can output to the screen fine, so no issue there.

```
echo('<button type="button" id="button'.$ctr.'" onClick="showMapsInfo('.$maps_name.', '.$ctr.');"><img src="img/maps_logo.gif"></button><br/>');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you just need to quote `$maps_name` and `$ctr` beforehand (since they're most likely strings:

```
echo('<button type="button" id="button'.$ctr.'" onClick="showMapsInfo(\''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $maps_name).'\', \''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $ctr).'\');"><img src="img/maps_logo.gif"></button><br/>');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, would've caught that one!